# I want to use python "loop" for drop list

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

```
import pandas as pd    
import os
import xlrd

os.chdir('D:\python')  
file_name='D:\python\\test.xlsx'      
sheet='test01'    
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet))  
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'Abc')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'def')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'ghi')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'jkl')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'mno')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'pqr')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

I want all variables(a to r) in one list so that all above condition passed in one sentence. for this I want to use loop.      Any suggestion on this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... can you provide some example input and output? Please have a look at how to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet))  
l = list(map(chr, range(97, ord('s'))))
li = [''.join(l[x:x+3]) for x in range(0, len(l), 3)]
for i in li:
    df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = i)), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some useful functions: **ord(char)** returns the ASCII value of a character;
**chr(int)** returns the character value of an int - hence we can construct a list as below

```
drop_list = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('r') + 1)]
print(drop_list)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r']
```